fatek Activex Component not created
enter image description here
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        server = CreateObject("FaconSvr.FaconServer") 'Create the FaconServer object
        server.OpenProject(CurDir() & "\DEMO.fcs") ' Open the project file(D:\Demo.fcs)   '  CurDir() Proğramın Dizinini Olduğu Yolu Verir
        ' which was created previously
        ConnectBtn.PerformClick()

I have a code string like this but I get the error "ActiveX component could not be created"
Can anyone with information about Fatek help me please?
I couldn't find how to solve the problem.
enter image description here
enter image description here
